# run HTML page with querystrings from aspx page without redirect

Tags: asp.net

From my asp.net 4.0 forms Application (C#) I need to Call a HTML page With 2 querystrings but I don't want to redirect to it, as I'm doing it from within a loop in code behind and the same HTML page will get called many times, With different querystrings.

I thought this could be done With a webrequest, but I'm unable to make it work. This technique is a bit out of my League so I would appreciate some advice on how to understand why and what I should do to make this work.

What I tried:

```
string testUri = "http://<URL>/velkommen.html?mailto=someone@someplace.no&profildata=ktrlg";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(testUri); 
//request.Method = "GET"; 
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); 
Response.Write("StatusDescription: " + response.StatusDescription + "<br />"); 
response.Close();
```

Status shows: OK. But nothing happens.

Comment: Show us what you try until now.

Comment: string testUri = "http://<URL>/velkommen.html?mailto=someone@someplace.no&profildata=ktrlg";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(testUri);
//request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Response.Write("StatusDescription: " + response.StatusDescription + "<br />");
response.Close();

Comment: Thanks for adding code, but it would be more clear if you can edit your question and put code there (with code formating)

Answer (score 0):

```
var cli = new System.Net.WebClient();
for(int i=0;i<url.Length;i++)
{
    url = "baseurl/data.asp?param=" + url[i].param;
    cli.DownloadString(url);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing here. What does "cli.DownloadString(url)" actually do?

Comment: downloadString(url) make http request to address and return response of website as string. I check you code and saw that you receive Status: OK, is means that http request is successful. What are you expecting after calling your html page? What is happens when you just open full url with querystring paramaters in web browser? Because now it looks like your request is completed without errors but may be website expecting POST request instead of GET?